Ruby method flock does not lock file when the file is inside docker bind mount
I have written following script for easier showing the problem:
require 'pathname'
class FlockTest
  def initialize
    @file_path = Pathname(File.join(Dir.pwd, 'tmp_test/file.lock'))
    puts "first opened file"
    @file = file_path.open(File::WRONLY | File::CREAT)
  end

  attr_reader :file_path, :file

  def test
    flock
    reopen_file
    flock
    reopen_file
    flock
  ensure
    file.close
    File.delete(file_path)
  end

  def reopen_file
    @file = file_path.open(File::WRONLY | File::CREAT)
    puts "reopened file"
  end

  def flock
    puts "flock: #{file.flock(File::LOCK_EX | File::LOCK_NB)}"
  end
end

FlockTest.new.test

Steps to recreate
Run script in docker container with mount bind:
mkdir tmp_test
docker run -it --rm --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)/lock.rb",target="/lock.rb" --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)/tmp_test",target="/tmp_test" ruby:3.0.7 bash
ruby lock.rb

Actual result
Second flock is returning 0, but it should false, because it is already locked.
first opened file
flock: 0
reopened file
flock: 0
reopened file
flock: false

Additional information
When calling without volume, it works good:
docker run -it --rm --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)/lock.rb",target="/lock.rb" ruby:3.0.7 bash
mkdir tmp_test
ruby lock.rb

Second flock returns false.
first opened file
flock: 0
reopened file
flock: false
reopened file
flock: false


I call it from mac os.
When I call lock.rb from mac (without docker) it also works good


Protip: instead of using puts like this use Minitest (it's bundled with Ruby by default) and write assertions. That way anyone can recreate your steps simply by running the test.
